# Gcloud builds submit fails on "global" violates constraint "constraints/gcp.resourceLocations"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am working a lot with the Google Cloud Platform. Last year, we instated the resource constraint policy "constraints/gcp.resourceLocations" to Europe only. As of today, we are seeing a lot of strange errors when submitting a cloud build. Does anyone know if Google recently changed something in their Cloud Build service and make it regional?

The following command used to work:

```
gcloud builds submit .
```

However, overnight (12 november 2020), we got the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) FAILED_PRECONDITION: "global" violates
> constraint "constraints/gcp.resourceLocations" on the resource
> "projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/builds/[UUID]"
>
> - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure   violations:
>
>   - description: '"global" violates constraint "constraints/gcp.resourceLocations"

When running the following command:

```
gcloud builds submit . --region=europe-west1
```

The following error appears:

> ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) User [USER] does not have permission to
> access projects instance [PROJECT_ID] (or it may not exist): project
> is not on the allowlist for Regional Cloud Build, please contact
> cloud-build-contact@google.com

Comment: Great question and no answer... Did you contact the provided email? There is lot of change in Cloud Build in preparation, and I guess the regionalization is one of these.

Comment: Hoped someone else would find this post! We decided to turn off the policy for now, since it concerns the production infrastructure as well. The provided e-mail is shut down for some reason, so we are going to contact support directly. I will update if we have a resolution.

Comment: Great! In our company, we have a test organisation where we try Organisation policy, because sometime, there is side effect like this... Anyway, the answer of Google support will be interesting. Keep us posted!

Comment: Yes, we have the same procedure, we always test on a separate folder, which holds all the development projects. But this was an unintended side effect from Google, for which I saw no announcement. We had a similar issue before where project default buckets were in another region than the policy prescribed, which caused cloud build to break.

Answer (score 0):

That was an internal issue on the GCP side, which has been fixed shortly by the Cloud Build engineering team.

Comment: Do you have a source/url verifying your statement?

Comment: @Nebulastic Could you please confirm if the issue has been resolved on your side as well?

Comment: Still the same issue. I had some hopes when I specified --region=europe. It then said: Try one of [asia-east1, asia-southeast1, europe-west1, europe-west4, us-central1, us-east1].

Comment: Hello, this might be because the Europe regions are further specified as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available) and thus the command --region=europe will not work. Please correct me if I misunderstood anything.